# CSS and JS not loading in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento

Hi I have installed the latest version of Magento but it is not loading any CSS or JS files.

Ihave it installed locally on WAMP but am not getting any Errors there. The JS console says:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):23 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):17 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):19 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/css/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):18 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):22 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/requirejs/require.js net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):126 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/images/magento-logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):23 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub/static/version1514906660/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
requirejs-config.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:16
    at requirejs-config.js:17
    at requirejs-config.js:440
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:16
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:17
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:440
(index):28 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):28
(anonymous) @ (index):28
(index):77 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):77
```

went to \magento\pub\static\adminhtml\Magento\backend\en_GB and removed the requiresjs-config after doing a bit of research in to the same issue but no results it seems to be putting a version number into the request is this possibly the issue?

Comment: is the server running in port 80?

Comment: tried the solution discussed here also but no result https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/magento-2-404-error-for-scripts-and-css/64808#64808

Comment: yeah its on port 80

Comment: Run this command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [locales]

Comment: hi tried running that command but still no result...tried this too https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183871/62355

Comment: this seems to be a common problem but theres loads of people trying different things to try fix it and some work for some people but none of them seem to be working for me

Comment: they are all static links now (don't have version numbers) the network part of the console is showing them all as 404s though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following step-:

In Magento web root-

**Step 1.** `$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Step 2.** `$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

**Step 3.** make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server

**Step 4.** $ `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2`

**Step 5.**

```
$ chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/magento2/ 
$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/var/
$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
```

**Step 6.** delete cache folder under var/cache

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.